# Error: You can't create entries as long as previously created entries are still open

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, zip, .net-4.5

I've created à Zip maker in VB.NET and I've this error :

> You can't create entries as long as previously created entries are still open.

(Translated from French : Impossible de créer des entrées tant que les entrées créées précédemment sont toujours ouvertes.)

My code is :

```
Dim filearchive As FileStream = New FileStream(My.Settings.archive_path, FileMode.CreateNew)
Dim archive As ZipArchive = New ZipArchive(filearchive, ZipArchiveMode.Create)
For Each File In FileIO.FileSystem.GetFiles(My.Settings.contacts_path)
    Dim crentry As ZipArchiveEntry = archive.CreateEntry(File)
    filearchive.CopyTo(crentry.Open())
    ProgressBar1.Increment(1)
    Label3.Text = ProgressBar1.Value.ToString + " %"
Next
```

I use .NET Framework 4.5 in VS 2010 and I've imported System.IO.Compression in my Class

Can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code to do what you want can be much simpler than that. Reference both *System.IO.Compression.dll* and *System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll* and then do this:

```vb
Using archive = ZipFile.Open(My.Settings.archive_path, ZipArchiveMode.Create)
    For Each filePath In Directory.EnumerateFiles(My.Settings.contacts_path)
        archive.CreateEntryFromFile(filePath, Path.GetFileName(filePath))
        '...
    Next
End Using
```

That will name each entry using the file name only. If you want the full file path, omit the `Path.GetFileName` call.

You might also look at the `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory` method to see whether that will do what you want in a single call.